# dynamically set anchor reference will not show but download

Tags: javascript, html, pdf, anchor, overwrite

I am facing a roblem where html page anchor href set in html opens a pdf in the same window BUT when href is set in javascript it just downloads the document. I need to open the dynamically-set doc in current browser window. Page uses java query 1 7 1 js. The href is tried and true.

forcing target="_self" does not help, it is default anyways
any function of onclick applied to the anchor tag fires but is ignored. tried regular js as well as jquery
happens in IE, Safari, Chrome, did not try others but not interested for now

I am open to try any suggestions.

not moodyfying the above to be honest in respect to the kind person who answered first.

here is what I found thanks to the answer: 
It doesn't matter if the link is set dynamically, nothing wrong with the pdf document, problem seems to be the location of the doc.
When I reference that doc in one domain it opens in current browser just fine, only the new domain location creates this problem ( I copied the old document there ).

Answer (score 0):

> *I need to open the dynamically-set doc in current browser window.*

The opening of PDF inside the browser, is a browser dependent feature. Google Chrome does it by default and Firefox needs Adobe Reader to be installed.

> *forcing* `target="_self"` *does not help, it is default anyways any function of onclick applied to the anchor tag fires but is ignored.*

If you don't give anything, by default, the browser opens in the same window. If it downloads, check for the response header having `Content-disposition: attachment;` and check with a browser, that supports opening of PDF.

Comment: please read the question it says statically set href opens the pdf in current window but when it is set dynamically it downloads, the two links are on the same page

Comment: @RadoslawDziegielewski What about the browser, and what about the Adobe Reader installation? Please enlighten. :)

Comment: It's not just Adobe Reader that you need, you also need a plugin for opening Adobe Reader in-browser (it installs during Adobe reader installation unless specifically disabled).
Also, not every browser opens links in "self" by default. Since the start of tabbed browsing, most browsers give you the option to open new links in a new tab. But yet again, this is a browser setting, not a coding issue.

Comment: @RadoslawDziegielewski sorry, but still I am unable to understand. :( Lets see if others are able to answer. :)

Comment: Lets say I have a http://www.somedomain.xyz/asdf.pdf and the link to that doc opens it in current window. Now I copy the doc to http://www.someotherdomain.xyz/asdf.pdf and the link fires a download.

Comment: OKay... Lets see in firebug how the response is. See like as I said, is there a `Content-disposition` header. This is a pure server side response thing.

Comment: Mozilla's Firebug pretends I did not click the anchor but Safari got me the header information and it is like you said: Content-Disposition:attachment;filename="asdf.pdf"

Comment: anything I can do on client-side to remove the header? Otherwise Thank You for helping me finding the reason of this issue.

Comment: You can't do this on the client side. It is an aspect of server side. `Content-disposition` should be `inline` for displaying it in the web page. For firebug, you need to see the **Network** panel, not the **Console**. :)